# want to connect the SearchView to the Mainactivity data - making a notepad app with search view to be connected to notes of notepad

Tags: java, android, searchview

I created a resource menu file i did all the xml work and also added the

` public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

```
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);
    MenuItem item=menu.findItem(R.id.Search);
    SearchView searchView=(SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {

            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;

}`
```

Now how do I connect my data of notes which is created by user. And once he tries to use the search bar he should be able search among words or notes he has created.

Comment: Weak title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 2):

> You have to write your search query listener in your
> onOptionsItemSelected() instead of OnCreateOptionsMenu like:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.search_item:
                searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                       //your logic of search goes here...
                   
                        searchView.clearFocus();  //disables the keyboard show up on rotation.
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                        return true;
                    }
                });

                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Is this fixed now the issue?

Comment: okay i am bit new would please define how we define the mquery or query are they local variables or predefined values? Please elaborate im breaking my head for 2 days for this search button to work.

Comment: Updated ans pls check

Comment: Thank you for your time, this however didn't solve my complete problem :)

Comment: What is the problem? My answer posted answers to your question...ask a new question or update your question with the issue occurring.